# How to copy a existing stored procedure ( .sql file ) into a MS SQL Server 2008R2 database with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssms

I had on another PC a database which did contain a stored procedure, I could see it in the object explorer of MS SQL Server Management Studio like in the picture below:
[image]

My web-application connected to the SQL database executes this procedure `sql.execute("dbo.calculateLiftUp")`

Now I switched everything to another location and the old Database is gone.
I a new instance of a MS SQL Server 2008R2 database and I created a new database.

Now I need to add to this database `test_db`( which has no stored procedure in the moment )
my `dbo.calculateLiftUp` stored procedure from this file `calculateLiftUp.sql`

[image]

I worked with this manual:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
I followed the steps, pasted the code from the `calculateLiftUp.sql` file into the new stored procedure and everything was possible until:

> 8.To create the stored procedure, on the Query menu, click Execute.

The problem is that the stored procedure wants to `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[calculateLiftUp]` which is not possible because the stored procedure does not exist. But regarding to the manual you have to execute the stored procedure in order to create it.

[image]

My question is: How can I add this file `calculateLiftUp.sql` as a stored procedure into a database.

Comment: The short answer is, change `ALTER` to `CREATE` in your script. The longer answer is that you should probably spend some time becoming familiar with executing scripts and ad hoc SQL queries in SSMS. There is a lot of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173(v=sql.100).aspx) and of course if you have a test server than you can do whatever you like.